# Drupal field collection error

Tags: entities

I tried using Drupal field collection module. I am getting the following error when I try to save the content using this field collection. I tried searching for anything related but couldn't find any resources

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'revision_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO {field_collection_item_revision} (item_id, ds_switch, _deleted, _rev) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 5 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 1-ba69446ba6019904db7085d3af46e6f2 ) in Drupal\multiversion\Entity\Storage\Sql\NodeStorage->save() (line 160 of modules\multiversion\src\Entity\Storage\ContentEntityStorageTrait.php).
```